# Keep trying to send data when lost internet or server down

Tags: curl, connection, cakephp-1.3

Can any one help me on cakephp 1.3. I need to send data to another server used CURL and the function keep trying to send data if lost connection, then stop when receive 'ok' message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set time out of the connecting in your application config

Comment: To make this a more complete answer, why not show an example of a snippet that configures the timeout?